# Dropdown spring boot

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot

I have 3 dropdowns, Country, State and City. In the form to register an ocntact they work fine. But when I want to update a contact, it looks for the value that has that contact in the database and each one is very slow, because in the database of cities there are 85780 entries.

This is my code:

```
 <select class="form-control" th:field="${contact.country}" id="countrySelect" onchange="loadStates()">
                      <option value="">Selecciona un país</option>
                      <!-- Renderizar opciones de países desde el controlador -->
                      <option th:each="country : ${countries}" th:value="${country.id}"     th:text="${country.name}"></option>
                    </select>


 <select class="form-control" th:field="${contact.state}" id="stateSelect" onchange="loadCities()">
                      <option value="">Selecciona un estado</option>
                      <!-- Renderizar opciones de estados desde el controlador -->
                      <option th:each="state : ${states}" th:value="${state.id}" th:text="${state.name}"></option>
                    </select>


 <select class="form-control" th:field="${contact.city}" id="citySelect">
                      <option value="">Selecciona una ciudad</option>
                      <!-- Renderizar opciones de ciudades desde el controlador -->
                      <option th:each="city : ${cities}" th:value="${city.id}" th:text="${city.name}"></option>
                    </select>
```

It also has a javascript code, that depending on the Country, it shows the corresponding States and the same with City.

```
<script>
  // Función para cargar estados al seleccionar un país
  function loadStates() {
    var countryId = $("#countrySelect").val();
    if (countryId === "") {
      $("#stateSelect").empty().prop("disabled", true);
      $("#citySelect").empty().prop("disabled", true);
      return;
    }

    $.get("/states", { countryId: countryId }, function(data) {
      $("#stateSelect").empty().prop("disabled", false);
      $("#citySelect").empty().prop("disabled", true);
      $("#stateSelect").append(new Option("Selecciona un estado", ""));

      // Iterar sobre los estados y establecer el estado actual del contacto como seleccionado
      $.each(data, function(index, state) {
        var selected = state.id === "${contact.state.id}" ? "selected" : "";
        $("#stateSelect").append(new Option(state.name, state.id, false, selected));
      });
    });
  }

  // Función para cargar ciudades al seleccionar un estado
  function loadCities() {
    var stateId = $("#stateSelect").val();
    if (stateId === "") {
      $("#citySelect").empty().prop("disabled", true);
      return;
    }

    $.get("/cities", { stateId: stateId }, function(data) {
      $("#citySelect").empty().prop("disabled", false);
      $("#citySelect").append(new Option("Selecciona una ciudad", ""));

      // Iterar sobre las ciudades y establecer la ciudad actual del contacto como seleccionada
      $.each(data, function(index, city) {
        var selected = city.id === "${contact.city.id}" ? "selected" : "";
        $("#citySelect").append(new Option(city.name, city.id, false, selected));
      });
    });
  }

  // Ejecutar loadStates() al cargar la página para mostrar los estados correspondientes
  $(document).ready(function() {
    loadStates();
  });
</script>
```